# $promotion->apply($order) doesn't work

Tags: 8, commerce

I have a redemption form that I want to enter a coupon code and then an order should be created automatically, then the coupon code applied to the order as well.

The order gets created successfully but `$promotion->apply($order)` does not work.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, I have a promotion containing coupon code `Z-8FDA5A218B44` . In the condition section, this promotion is limited to a product called `Monthly`.

I want to create a redemption form in which when a user enters a coupon code, an order and an order item that contains my product (Monthly) will be automatically created. (picture below)

[image]
As you can see when I submit the redemption form with a coupon code, an order will be created, but I want to apply the coupon code to the order too.

Here's my code:

```
namespace Drupal\my_subscription\Form;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy;
use Drupal\commerce_product\Plugin\Commerce\Condition\OrderItemProduct as OrderItemProductCondition;
use Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order;
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariation;


/**
 * Class RedemptionForm.
 *
 * @package Drupal\my_subscription\Form
 */
class RedemptionForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy definition.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy
   */
  protected $currentUser;

  public function __construct(
    AccountProxy $current_user
  ) {
    $this->currentUser = $current_user;
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('current_user')
    );
  }


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'meditation_redemption_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['coupon_code'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Coupon code'),
      '#description' => t('Enter your coupon code to redeem a promotion.'),
    ];

    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $coupon_code = $form_state->getValue('coupon_code');
    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_promotion\CouponStorageInterface $coupon_storage */
    $coupon_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_promotion_coupon');

    $coupon = $coupon_storage->loadByCode($coupon_code);
    if (empty($coupon)) {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('coupon_code', t('The provided coupon code is invalid.'));
      return;
    }
    else {
      $form_state->set('coupon', $coupon);
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_promotion\Entity\Coupon $coupon */
    $coupon = $form_state->get('coupon');
    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_promotion\Entity\Promotion $promotion */
    $promotion = $coupon->getPromotion();

    $conditions = $promotion->getConditions();
    if ($conditions[0] instanceof OrderItemProductCondition) {
      $uid = $this->currentUser->id();

      $configuration = $conditions[0]->getConfiguration();
      $subscription_product_id = $configuration['products'][0]['product_id'];

      $subscription = ProductVariation::load($subscription_product_id);

      $order_item_storage = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('commerce_order_item');

      $order_item = $order_item_storage->createFromPurchasableEntity($subscription, [
        'quantity' => 1,
      ]);

      /** @var \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order $order */
      $order = Order::create([
        'type' => 'default',
      ]);
      $order->addItem($order_item);
      $order->setCustomerId($uid);
      $order->set('store_id', 1);
      $order->save();
      ///** @var  \Drupal\commerce_ORDER\OrderAssignment $order_assignment */
      //$order_assignment = \Drupal::service('commerce_order.order_assignment');
      //$order_assignment->assign($order, $account);

      if ($coupon->available($order) && $promotion->applies($order)) {
        $promotion->apply($order);
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Is it failing due to the available and applies check, not actually apply? Also, try setting refresh on next load possibly, to rerun refresh

Comment: Dear @MattGlaman, both available and applies are passed. And what do you mean about refresh?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm maybe TLTTP but it appears that your implementation is right (assuming as you say it passes the **available** and **applies** checks). The problem I think is that you're not saving the order after the promotion gets applied.

```
...
if ($coupon->available($order) && $promotion->applies($order)) {
    $promotion->apply($order);
    $order->save();
}
...
```

Also as [@matt-glaman](/users/13179) [suggests](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/241729/promotion-applyorder-doesnt-work-in-commerce-v2-0-rc1#comment295860_241729) you should *refresh* the order so the final price gets updated.

```
...
if ($coupon->available($order) && $promotion->applies($order)) {
    $promotion->apply($order);
    // Recalculates total price of the order including any adjustment
    // to the order or it's order items.
    $order->recalculateTotalPrice();
    // Persist any changes applied to the order.
    $order->save();
}
...
```